# Google analytics for HTML inside ios native app

Tags: html, ios, google-analytics

I've build an ios application that is having static HTML pages. I'm using uiwebview to create container for my HTML pages.

Now I want to use google analytics for my pages. I've downloaded its SDK and it is working. Now I would like to track events on some of buttons on HTML page. If use below code

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<Acc no>']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Along with `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent',...)` not tracking required event.

Can I do pagetracking with SDK and event tracking in normal web HTML method?

Comment: I've been looking for an answer for this. I ended up using the Native SDK and manually calling trackpageview on each HTML load inside the webview.

Comment: The Google Analytics iOS v2 SDK [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/) allows a easiest way to track event/pages

Comment: If you need, you can also use [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html) for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the Google Analytics native SDK and make it react using the UIWebviewDelegate or Javascript events.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you need to call native function through JS. So implement this function `-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;` and fire a dummy url from ur JS and add all the tracking info to it separated by slash(/). For ex: `window.location = '#abc://something.com/'+page;` (# here is used for some other reason, not relevant here).
Now all that you have to do is, just extract the url string parameters inside the function i wrote earlier and pass it on to your GA code, which will call its tracking method with your page value.